# Compare DB query with website value in Selenium Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, extentreports

I am working on a project where I use **Selenium** as the testing tool, is there any way that I can compare the values in the website and the values in the DB are same?. Is it possible to create a test case for that?... I use java 1.8 and eclipse IDE!.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. Java is a feature-rich programming language. You can connect to and query databases via JDBC, for example. Selenium is just another library (like JDBC) that you are using with Java.